# ubuntu 12.10 lock-screen unlockable with old ldap password

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen, openldap

I have an ldap server that serves Ubuntu clients and there is a problem when unlocking the screen after a user has changed their password.

Initial login works as expected: the user can log in with the new password and cannot with the old one. However the user is able to unlock the lock-screen with both the new and the old passwords.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: This also seems to apply for other PAM methods and the lock screen. In my case, I'm trying out pam-blue.